# MemoryError when multiplying CSR sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have created a Document-Term Matrix using Sklearn and TfidfVectorizer.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf = True, 
                        norm = normalization,
                        min_df = min_doc_freq) 

dtm = tfidf.fit_transform(text)
```

This gives a 128,111 x 3,469 sparse matrix, CSR format with 1,865,094 stored elements. I want to multiply it by it's transpose, but every time I do, I get a Memory Error.

The matrix is 128,111 x 3,469, meaning that the resulting matrix should be 128,111 x 128,111, which doesn't seem THAT big.

I am using Python 3.7.2, 64 bit. As of this writing, the VM I'm using has 84 gigs of RAM available to use (it has over 125 in total).

I have tried the following code and get the same error each time:

```
sim = dtm * dtm.T #(also used dtm.transpose()) 

sim = dtm @ dtm.T 

sim = dtm.dot(dtm.T)
```

I expected a sparse matrix to be returned, but I get "MemoryError".

```
 ~/utilities/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other) 
 500 maxval=nnz) 
 501 indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype) 
 --> 502 indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype) 
 503 data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype)) 
 504 MemoryError:
```

Comment: Can you show a traceback?  That is, show us where in the matrix multiplication process it's hitting the memory limit.

Comment: Is this what you're asking for? Sorry for such a basic question.
~/utilities/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    500                                     maxval=nnz)
    501         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 502         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    503         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    504 

MemoryError:

Comment: sparse does the multiplication in 2 steps.  First determines the number of nonzero values in the result, and the second calculates those values.  The error arises when it creates a `data` array to store those values.  The expected number of nonzero values is too large for the available memory.

Comment: @hpaulj That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for explaining this. Would you happen to have any suggestions for a work around?